# Whitelabel Error Page 404 when rendering view - Java Spring Boot

Tags: java, spring-boot, hibernate, maven, thymeleaf

I'm having an issue with rendering my html view trying to show a simple list of an object gathered from MySQL. I believe it should be a simple issue but I cant figure it out, I've searched hundreds of similar issues but can't solve mine. No logs are showing neither on Java console or cmd using mvn spring-boot:run

[image]

I'm able to gather correctly the info from MySQL with a DAO as I'm printing it on the console and it shows ok.. printing it on my Controller which looks like this

```
import org.slf4j.Logger;
import org.slf4j.LoggerFactory;
import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.GetMapping;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView;

import com.valuaciones_automoviles.afip.dao.VAutomovilesDao;

@Controller
public class VAutomovilesController {
    
    @Autowired
    VAutomovilesDao vaDao;
    
     private final Logger logger = LoggerFactory.getLogger(VAutomovilesController.class);
     
    @GetMapping("/")
    public ModelAndView index(){
        ModelAndView mv = new ModelAndView("index");
        
        mv.addObject("vaItems", vaDao.getVa());
        System.out.println(vaDao + "vaDao");
        logger.info(mv.toString());
        return mv;
    }
}
```

and this prints the following when hitting localhost:8080:

> Hibernate: select valuacione0_.in as in1_0_, valuacione0_.a2012 as a2_0_, valuacione0_.a2013 as a3_0_, valuacione0_.a2014 as a4_0_, valuacione0_.a2015 as a5_0_, valuacione0_.a2016 as a6_0_, valuacione0_.a2017 as a7_0_, valuacione0_.a2018 as a8_0_, valuacione0_.a2019 as a9_0_, valuacione0_.a2020 as a10_0_, valuacione0_.a2021 as a11_0_, valuacione0_.descripcion as descrip12_0_, valuacione0_.marca as marca13_0_, valuacione0_.tipo as tipo14_0_ from valuaciones_automoviles valuacione0_
> com.valuaciones_automoviles.afip.dao.VAutomovilesDao@17143b3bvaDao
> 2022-10-06 22:15:51.273  INFO 3516 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.v.a.controller.VAutomovilesController  : ModelAndView [view="index"; model={vaItems=[ValuacionesAutomoviles [id=1, marca=Ford, descripcion=4 puertas, tipo=auto, a2021=2121, a2020=44, a2019=2123, a2018=321, a2017=432, a2016=543, a2015=6, a2014=654, a2013=564, a2012=45]]}]

which looks ok

My index.html page is

```
<html xmlns:th="http://www.thymeleaf.org">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link th:rel="stylesheet" th:href="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.4.1/css/bootstrap.min.css} " />
</head>

<body>
    <div class="container">
        <h1 class="text-center">Autos</h1>
        <hr />
        <table class="table table-bordered table-striped">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>Description</th>
                    <th>Complete</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                 <tr th:each="item : ${vaItems}"> 
                     <td th:text="${item.marca}">marca</td> 
                     <td th:text="${item.descripcion}">descripcion</td> 
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </table>
    </div>


    <script th:src="@{/webjars/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js}"></script>
    <script th:src="@{/webjars/bootstrap/3.4.1/js/bootstrap.min.js}"></script>
</body>

</html>
```

My POM is:

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 https://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.7.4</version>
        <relativePath/> <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
    <groupId>com.valuaciones_automoviles</groupId>
    <artifactId>afip</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>afip</name>
    <description>Demo project for Spring Boot</description>
    <properties>
        <java.version>11</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>mysql</groupId>
            <artifactId>mysql-connector-java</artifactId>
            <scope>runtime</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.thymeleaf/thymeleaf -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
            <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>      
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
            <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/bootstrap -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>bootstrap</artifactId>
            <version>3.4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.webjars/jquery -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.webjars</groupId>
            <artifactId>jquery</artifactId>
            <version>3.6.0</version>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

And this is my project structure:

[image]

I'm not adding the DAO and Entity and Hibernate Util class as it seems they are working ok as I'm printing the object already. Any help would be highly appreciated, please let me know if any extra info is needed

This are the only logs I get when hitting localhost:8080, nothing else appears

[image]

> 2022-10-07 17:01:53.222  INFO 9408 --- [           main] c.v.afip.AfipApplication                 : Starting AfipApplication using Java 14.0.2 on DESKTOP-6LF9U81 with PID 9408 (C:\Users\JOTA\Desktop\Jota new projects\afip\afip\target\classes started by JOTA in C:\Users\JOTA\Desktop\Jota new projects\afip\afip)
> 2022-10-07 17:01:53.224  INFO 9408 --- [           main] c.v.afip.AfipApplication                 : No active profile set, falling back to 1 default profile: "default"
> 2022-10-07 17:01:54.256  INFO 9408 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat initialized with port(s): 8080 (http)
> 2022-10-07 17:01:54.271  INFO 9408 --- [           main] o.apache.catalina.core.StandardService   : Starting service [Tomcat]
> 2022-10-07 17:01:54.271  INFO 9408 --- [           main] org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngine  : Starting Servlet engine: [Apache Tomcat/9.0.65]
> 2022-10-07 17:01:54.430  INFO 9408 --- [           main] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring embedded WebApplicationContext
> 2022-10-07 17:01:54.431  INFO 9408 --- [           main] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 1171 ms
> 2022-10-07 17:01:54.694  INFO 9408 --- [           main] o.s.b.a.w.s.WelcomePageHandlerMapping    : Adding welcome page template: index
> 2022-10-07 17:01:54.857  INFO 9408 --- [           main] o.s.b.w.embedded.tomcat.TomcatWebServer  : Tomcat started on port(s): 8080 (http) with context path ''
> 2022-10-07 17:01:54.867  INFO 9408 --- [           main] c.v.afip.AfipApplication                 : Started AfipApplication in 1.979 seconds (JVM running for 2.428)
> 2022-10-07 17:01:54.944  INFO 9408 --- [           main] org.hibernate.Version                    : HHH000412: Hibernate ORM core version 5.6.11.Final
> 2022-10-07 17:01:55.100  INFO 9408 --- [           main] o.hibernate.annotations.common.Version   : HCANN000001: Hibernate Commons Annotations {5.1.2.Final}
> 2022-10-07 17:01:55.178  WARN 9408 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001002: Using Hibernate built-in connection pool (not for production use!)
> 2022-10-07 17:01:55.182  INFO 9408 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001005: using driver [com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver] at URL [jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/importar?useSSL=false]
> 2022-10-07 17:01:55.182  INFO 9408 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001001: Connection properties: {password=****, user=root}
> 2022-10-07 17:01:55.182  INFO 9408 --- [           main] org.hibernate.orm.connections.pooling    : HHH10001003: Autocommit mode: false
> 2022-10-07 17:01:55.184  INFO 9408 --- [           main] .c.i.DriverManagerConnectionProviderImpl : HHH000115: Hibernate connection pool size: 20 (min=1)
> 2022-10-07 17:01:55.334  INFO 9408 --- [           main] org.hibernate.dialect.Dialect            : HHH000400: Using dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
> Hibernate: select valuacione0_.in as in1_0_, valuacione0_.a2012 as a2_0_, valuacione0_.a2013 as a3_0_, valuacione0_.a2014 as a4_0_, valuacione0_.a2015 as a5_0_, valuacione0_.a2016 as a6_0_, valuacione0_.a2017 as a7_0_, valuacione0_.a2018 as a8_0_, valuacione0_.a2019 as a9_0_, valuacione0_.a2020 as a10_0_, valuacione0_.a2021 as a11_0_, valuacione0_.descripcion as descrip12_0_, valuacione0_.marca as marca13_0_, valuacione0_.tipo as tipo14_0_ from valuaciones_automoviles valuacione0_
> ValuacionesAutomoviles [id=1, marca=Ford, descripcion=4 puertas, tipo=auto, a2021=2121, a2020=44, a2019=2123, a2018=321, a2017=432, a2016=543, a2015=6, a2014=654, a2013=564, a2012=45]testtttt
> 2022-10-07 17:02:02.911  INFO 9408 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring DispatcherServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
> 2022-10-07 17:02:02.911  INFO 9408 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing Servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
> 2022-10-07 17:02:02.912  INFO 9408 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Completed initialization in 0 ms
> Hibernate: select valuacione0_.in as in1_0_, valuacione0_.a2012 as a2_0_, valuacione0_.a2013 as a3_0_, valuacione0_.a2014 as a4_0_, valuacione0_.a2015 as a5_0_, valuacione0_.a2016 as a6_0_, valuacione0_.a2017 as a7_0_, valuacione0_.a2018 as a8_0_, valuacione0_.a2019 as a9_0_, valuacione0_.a2020 as a10_0_, valuacione0_.a2021 as a11_0_, valuacione0_.descripcion as descrip12_0_, valuacione0_.marca as marca13_0_, valuacione0_.tipo as tipo14_0_ from valuaciones_automoviles valuacione0_
> com.valuaciones_automoviles.afip.dao.VAutomovilesDao@2bc378f7vaDao
> 2022-10-07 17:02:02.935  INFO 9408 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] c.v.a.controller.VAutomovilesController  : ModelAndView [view="index"; model={vaItems=[ValuacionesAutomoviles [id=1, marca=Ford, descripcion=4 puertas, tipo=auto, a2021=2121, a2020=44, a2019=2123, a2018=321, a2017=432, a2016=543, a2015=6, a2014=654, a2013=564, a2012=45]]}]
> 2022-10-07 17:02:02.968 ERROR 9408 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[.[.[/].[dispatcherServlet]    : Servlet.service() for servlet [dispatcherServlet] threw exception
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:210) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:148) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1405) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1149) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1088) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:403) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:249) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]
> 2022-10-07 17:02:02.969 ERROR 9408 --- [nio-8080-exec-1] o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost]           : Exception Processing ErrorPage[errorCode=0, location=/error]
> javax.servlet.ServletException: Circular view path [error]: would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup! (Hint: This may be the result of an unspecified view, due to default view name generation.)
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.prepareForRendering(InternalResourceView.java:210) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceView.renderMergedOutputModel(InternalResourceView.java:148) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.view.AbstractView.render(AbstractView.java:316) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.render(DispatcherServlet.java:1405) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.processDispatchResult(DispatcherServlet.java:1149) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doDispatch(DispatcherServlet.java:1088) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet.doService(DispatcherServlet.java:964) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.processRequest(FrameworkServlet.java:1006) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.doGet(FrameworkServlet.java:898) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:655) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.service(FrameworkServlet.java:883) ~[spring-webmvc-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:4.0.FR]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.RequestContextFilter.doFilterInternal(RequestContextFilter.java:100) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:117) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter.doFilter(OncePerRequestFilter.java:102) ~[spring-web-5.3.23.jar:5.3.23]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.invoke(ApplicationDispatcher.java:711) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.processRequest(ApplicationDispatcher.java:461) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.doForward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:385) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationDispatcher.forward(ApplicationDispatcher.java:313) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.custom(StandardHostValve.java:403) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.status(StandardHostValve.java:249) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:360) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:890) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1789) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61) ~[tomcat-embed-core-9.0.65.jar:9.0.65]
> at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:832) ~[na:na]

Comment: Can you check your error logs? It will have an exact error. By using your above code with a different entity I can see it running without any issues.

Comment: I've added an image of the logs that show when hitting the page, I dont get any exact logs, idk why

Comment: Can you add `server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false`  or `spring.autoconfigure.exclude=org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.servlet.error.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration` to application.properties and check? Does it show an actual error instead of a Whitelabel page?

Comment: I've used server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false and got logs, thanks! Added the logs to the post

Comment: It seems there is a configuration issue with thymeleaf. Can you provide thymeleaf configuration?

Comment: Thanks to your comments I was able to figure out at some point I added a XXX.thymeleaf=disabled on my application.properties... infuriating but its my first times doing it so i guess I shouldn't be too mad. Thanks for the help.. (you can add an answer and I'll mark it as the answer for this question)

Answer (score 0):

From logs, it seems configuration issue of thymeleaf. As it's not finding templates and the error says `would dispatch back to the current handler URL [/error] again. Check your ViewResolver setup!`

From your last comment, you have thymeleaf disabled in application.properties. **Enable thymeleaf** and check it should work.